# SKAction Perform Selector syntax error

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

Using a SKAction sequence I am trying to add a delay and then call a method with two parameters, however I keep getting the following (new to obj c so could be something simple):

```
// code 
SKAction *fireAction = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:1.5 withRange:0],
                                [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addExplosion:firstBody.node.position  andTheName: @"whiteExplosion") onTarget:self]]];
```

// error

> Expected ':'

Method declaration

```
-(void) addExplosion : (CGPoint) position andTheName :(NSString *) explosionName{
```

When I substitute a method call without parameters seems to work fine.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[SKAction runBlock:^{}]` instead of a selector.

I would use selectors if the method has no parameters. Using a block is much more powerful. But beware of how to use them as it may keep expected deleted objects alive.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
SKAction *fireAction = [SKAction sequence:@[
                        [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5 withRange:0],
                        [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [weakself addExplosion:position andTheName:explosionName];
}]]];
```

Or use the completion block:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
SKAction *fireAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5 withRange:0];

[someNode runAction:fireAction completion:^{
    [weakself addExplosion:position andTheName:explosionName];
}];
```

Comment: Is weakself necessary in this case?

Comment: Thanks, not sure about the weak reference to self, I this to avoid a retain cycle?

Comment: I don't think weakself here is needed because the action also runs on the self object. If the node (self) is removed from the scene it cleans up (removes) all of its actions and therefore there can't be a retain cycle.

Comment: Okay. First, thanks for the comments. Second, I was curious. What is said is partially correct. Don't need `weak` ref if it's the last action. However, if there any other actions running that used the `strong` ref, the scene would not be deallocated. I uploaded a scene code that test this: https://gist.github.com/naterhat/5399eec40eaa23edbfbc. Just treat the action block as GCD.  Please let me know if make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for @selector is:

```
 @selector(addExplosion:andTheName:)
```

You have to omit the actual variable names, just the parameter names should be specified.

Also allow me to suggest that "andTheName" is a bad parameter name, ObjC guidelines specifically state not to use "and". You lose nothing in readability if your selector parameters would be named like one of these two:

```
 @selector(addExplosion:name:)
 @selector(addExplosion:withName:)
```

Comment: OK but how do we pass arguments to the method call?

Comment: Actually you can't. The SKAction docs don't state it explicitly so I assume the selector has to be one that doesn't take parameters. If you want to pass in variable runBlock as in Nate's answer is the better alternative.

Comment: Ok cheers runBlock seems the better alternative thanks all for the feedback