# Sprite Kit leaks don't make sense

Tags: memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I have been running Instruments to see why my SKScene won't deallocate and getting "leaks" that don't make any sense. One of the "leaks" is on a scene that properly deallocates and points to this:

```
border.path = path;
```

As the line causing the leak but the very next line is:

```
CGPathRelease(path);
border.lineWidth = 1.0f;
border.strokeColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
[border setAlpha:0.0f];
[border runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0f duration:0.2f]];
[self addChild:border];
```

So you can clearly see it's released.I am also getting "leaks" for methods like:

```
-(void)explosionShake{
//[self testTargets];
NSArray *objectArray = [self children];
for (SKNode *node in objectArray) {
    [node runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0.0f, 10.0f) duration:.05] completion:^{
        [node runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0.0f, -15.0f) duration:.05] completion:^{
            [node runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0.0f, 5.0f) duration:.05]];
        }];
         }];
    }
```

}

After the scene ends, and also for another object which I remove from it's parent.

Could these "leaks" be caused by trying to run an action on a node that has been removed from it's parent? Because as "explosionshake" is running, one of the nodes may be removed from it's parent in another method. What about this method:

```
SKEmitterNode *testForExplosion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"explosionTest" ofType:@"sks"]];
//testForExplosion.position = location;
//[testForExplosion setParticleSpeed:self.frame.size.width/self.gameSpeed];
SKNode *node = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:node];
[node setPosition:location];
[node runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(-self.frame.size.width, 0) duration:self.gameSpeed]];
[node addChild:testForExplosion];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:4.0f];
SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:wait,remove, nil];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:array];
```

The first line in the method is highlighted in red and the last one in green (that's just a chunk of the method). I am pretty confused about why these are "leaks", but it's probably contributing to why my scene isn't getting deallocated.

If anybody could give me pointers as to why these methods could possibly be causing memory leaks, that would be very, very helpful. I have plenty more methods which are supposedly leaking `SKCSprite`s, when my code clearly calls `removeFromParent`

Comment: Do an analyze build in xcode if you haven't already. There can be false positives both in Instruments and Analyze. The explosionShake may leak the node because each completion block strongly references node, but there is no guarantee that each completion block runs (action could be stopped at any time). Creating a weak temporary variable for node would fix that if it is indeed a problem. The path is probabaky a false positive, seen that before.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have done an analyze build and only came up with one "possible leak", which I fixed. I would find it too good to be true that all the other leaks are false positives since the "leaks" instrument page shows a total of 33 leaks (although, after some modifications to my code, none of the leaks seem to link to any of MY code, which is weird), and my game scene is not deallocating which makes me think there's gotta be some sort of problem in the scene. Could it be that my iPhone is running iOS 7.1.2?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Also, could you provide me an example for how I'd create a "weak reference" to `node`? In all the tutorials I watched I never once saw something about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 
`SKShapeNode` are not the most solid class to use in the game. I mean, better to use a `SKSpriteNode` with a shape image. If still use `SKShapeNode`, try code below. May not work, but give it a try.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if(self.shapeNode){
        [self.shapeNode setPath:NULL];
        [self.shapeNode removeFromParent];
        self.shapeNode = nil;
    }
}
```

2)
It's clear that there is a strong reference to the node. May rewrite like:

```
-(void)explosionShake
{
    NSArray *objectArray = [self children];
    for (SKNode *node in objectArray) {

        // create a weak reference of the node
        __weak typeof(node) weaknode = node;

        // run action
        [node runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0.0f, 10.0f) duration:.05] completion:^{
            [weaknode runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0.0f, -15.0f) duration:.05] completion:^{
                [weaknode runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0.0f, 5.0f) duration:.05]];
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

3)
The third section seem to have some missing code because I don't see a leak.

Check this other thread for an example of how to run an action with a completion block.
[SKAction Perform Selector syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684063/skaction-perform-selector-syntax-error/26685420#26685420)
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I only want to clarify two things: 1, so actions that are done by `sequence` won't cause leaks, but `completion` blocks will? also, did you mean, in your answer, to run the first action on `node` and all the subsequent ones on `weaknode` instead of running all 3 on `weaknode`? why?

Comment: !) When using `SKAction` sequence, you are not creating a separate reference to the objects. You let Sprite Kit manage that. When use completion block or `SKAction` `runBlock` and calling a node, that block will create a strong reference to that node. When node is removed from parent, the block will keep node in memory. 2) doesn't matter, you can use `weaknode` if you want.

Comment: would this matter if running an action on `self` such as [`self runAction:action completion:^(void){block}]`? Would I need to use a "weak" version of "self"?

Comment: No. All that matters is inside the block. If use `self`, inside the block, then you may have a leak.

Comment: so, any objects I reference inside the block have to be weak? For example, in my code, I have `[weakSelf runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:.5f] completion:^{
            [self showTargetAtPositionIndex:2];
        }];` and I must also make the `self` inside of the block into `weakSelf` ?

Comment: That is correct. Otherwise, you know what happen if don't.