# Unable to locate memory leak using Xcode Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

### The problem

I discovered earlier that my memory usage in my game was only going up when the tiles were moved, but it never went back down again. From this, I could tell there was a memory leak.

I then started using Xcode Instruments, which I am very new to. So I followed many things from [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/01/25/ios-memory-leak-xcode/), especially the `Recording Options`, and then I set the mode to show the `Call Tree`.

### Results of Instruments

[image: Instruments - Results of testing for leaks]

### What do I need help with?

I have two functions that just move all the tiles along that row/column, and then clones the tile at the end (using `node.copy()`) so everything can "loopover", hence the project name.

I feel as if the tile cloning may be causing some retention cycle, however, it is stored in the variable within the function scope. After I run the `SKAction` on the clone, I remove the tile from the scene using `copiedNode.removeFromParent()`.

So what may be causing this memory leak? Could I be looking in the wrong place?

---

### Code

I have shortened this code to what I consider necessary.

Declaration at the top of the class:

```
/// Delegate to the game scene to reference properties.
weak var delegate: GameScene!
/// All the cloned tiles currently on the board.
private var cloneTiles = [SKSpriteNode]()
```

Cloning of the tile within the moving tiles functions:

```
/// A duplicate of the current tile.
let copiedNode = currentTile.node.copy() as! SKSpriteNode // Create copy
cloneTiles.append(copiedNode) // Add as a clone
delegate.addChild(copiedNode) // Add to the scene
let copiedNodeAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: movementDifference, y: 0, duration: animationDuration) // Create the movement action

// Run the action, and then remove itself
copiedNode.run(copiedNodeAction) {
    self.cloneTiles.remove(at: self.cloneTiles.firstIndex(of: copiedNode)!)
    copiedNode.removeFromParent()
}
```

Function to move tiles immediately:

```
/// Move all tiles to the correct location immediately.
private func moveTilesToLocationImmediately() {
    // Remove all clone tiles
    cloneTiles.forEach { $0.removeFromParent() }
    cloneTiles.removeAll()

    /* Moves tiles here */
}
```

Is there something I need to declare as a `weak var` or something? I know how retain cycles occur, but do not get why it exists in this code, as I remove the cloned tile reference from the `cloneTiles` array.

---

### Roughly where the leak is occurring (helped by `Mark Szymczyk`)

Here is what happened after I double-clicked on the move tiles function in the call stack (refer to his answer below):

[image: Instruments - Finding the memory leak]

This is confirming that the memory leak is caused somehow by the node clone, but I still don't know why this node is still being retained after it is removed from the `cloneTiles` array and the scene. Could the node be having trouble getting removed from the scene for some reason?

Please leave *any* tips or questions about this, so this problem can be solved!

### More investigating

I have now been trying to get to grips with Xcode Instruments, but I am still really struggling to find this memory leak. Here is the leaks panel which may help:

[image: Instruments - Leaks panel]

[image: Instruments - Leak's history]

Even after trying `[weak self]`, I still had no luck:

[image: Instruments - Using [weak self] within the closure]

Even the leaks history still looks the same with the `[weak self]` within the closure.

### Continuing to try to resolve the reference cycle

Currently, `@matt` is helping me with this issue. I have changed a few lines of code, by adding things like `[unowned self]`:

```
// Determine if the tile will roll over
if direction == .up && movementDifference < 0 || direction == .down && movementDifference > 0 {
    // Calculate where the clone tile should move to
    movementDifference -= rollOverDistance

    /// A duplicate of the current tile.
    let copiedNode = currentTile.node.copy() as! SKSpriteNode // Create copy
    cloneTiles.append(copiedNode) // Add as a clone
    delegate.addChild(copiedNode) // Add to the scene
    let copiedNodeAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: movementDifference, duration: animationDuration) // Create the movement action

    // Run the action, and then remove itself
    copiedNode.run(copiedNodeAction) { [unowned self, copiedNode] in
        self.cloneTiles.remove(at: self.cloneTiles.firstIndex(of: copiedNode)!).removeFromParent()
    }

    // Move the original roll over tile back to the other side of the screen
    currentTile.node.position.y += rollOverDistance
}

/// The normal action to perform, moving the tile by a distance.
let normalNodeAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: movementDifference, duration: animationDuration) // Create the action
currentTile.node.run(normalNodeAction) { [unowned self] in // Apply the action
    if forRow == 1 { self.animationsCount -= 1 } // Lower animation count for completion
}
```

Unfortunately, I could not make `copiedNode` a `weak` property as it would always be instantly `nil`, and `unowned` caused a crash about the reference being read after being deallocated. Here is also the `Cycles & Roots` graph if this is helpful:

[image: Instruments - Cycles & Roots graph]

---

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007350/sprite-kit-leaks-dont-make-sense You need every outside thing you reference inside the run SKAction to be weak. So not just self, but maybe also the copied node.

Comment: The whole problem seems to be this odd way you are holding on to an extra reference to the copied node and also having the node remove itself. I find that very confusing and weird. It's hard for me to make positive suggestions about this, but I would suggest using the weak-strong dance inside the run action so that _if_ the values arrive into the action handler they are retained as _local_ strong variables.

Comment: @matt Is there another method you would recommend, to store a cloned node in the `cloneTiles` array?

Comment: @matt I am also not sure what you mean by the "weak-strong dance". Do you mean that I remove the `[unowned self, copiedNode]` from the action, and then just inside, write `let copiedNodeRef = copiedNode`?

Comment: @matt With the comment above doing the optional binding, does that mean I need to declare `copiedNode` as `weak var`? Thank you so much for this help, it means a lot!

Comment: @matt I am new-ish to ARC and this has me slightly confused... I know that classes are referenced, but I cannot do `weak let`, what am I doing horribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rather suspicious of the way you're managing the copied node; you may be releasing it prematurely, and only the retain cycle was preventing you from discovering this mistake. However, let's concentrate on breaking the retain cycle.

What you want to do is make everything coming into the action method `weak`, so that there is no strong capture by the action method. Then in the action method you want to immediately retain those weak references so they don't vanish out from under you. That's called the "weak-strong dance". Like this:

```
    copiedNode.run(copiedNodeAction) { [weak self, weak copiedNode] in
        if let `self` = self, let copiedNode = copiedNode {
            // do stuff here
            // be sure to log so you know we arrived here at all, as we might not
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just as a little note, I didn't have to include the `weak self`, all I needed was the `weak copiedNode`.

Comment: And indeed that seems confirmed by the retain cycle diagram you posted, which shows the node pointing at itself.

Comment: I still don't understand those diagrams, but I guess I will learn in due time :p I am _almost_ at a year of Swift, as I started mid-February last year.

Comment: It also annoys me that some problems I have (like this) take so long to figure out, and are only 3 words off! A pain, but you definitely deserve the bounty (when I can award it).

Comment: You don't have to quote the local “self” with backticks anymore in Swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

I can help a little on the Instruments front. If you double-click the `moveHorizontally` entry in the Instruments call tree, Instruments will show you the lines of code that are allocating the leaked memory. At the bottom of the window is a Call Tree button. If you click on that, you can invert the call tree and hide system libraries. Doing that will make it easier to find your code in the call tree.

You can learn more about Instruments in the following article:

[Measuring Your App's Memory Usage with Instruments](https://swiftdevjournal.com/measuring-your-apps-memory-usage-with-instruments/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the instruments help! I will now update the question using the help you gave to detect the line which is allocating the leaked memory. I will just try again before updating the question though, just to see if I can figure it out myself. Thank you so much for your great help once again! 